# Iterating over json data consists of many None type objects

Tags: python, json, iteration, nonetype

I am trying to iterate over json data. Here is the data structure that I have

```
import requests
import re
url = "https://web.archive.org/__wb/calendarcaptures?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unibocconi.it&selected_year=2014"
# You can see the data structure by copy-pasting the link
data = requests.get(url).json()
    for x in data:
       for y in x:
           for z in y:
               for xx in z:
                    start1 = "'ts': "
                    start2 = "'st': "
                    h = str(xx)
                    a = re.search('%s(.*)' % (start1) , h).group(1)
                    date = a[:16].replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
                    date = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", date)
                    b = re.search('%s(.*)' % (start2) , h).group(1)
                    status = b[:5].replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

I know, I can not iterate over the None type objects. But I could not solve the problem for couple of hours. Any ideas?
Note: I get json data directly from the web by using requests

Comment: @pault It appears to be defined starting with the first line of his code, which begins, `data =`

Comment: `None` is not valid in JSON. It should be `null`.

Comment: Actually this is what I get, but None might be a string...

Comment: @edyvedy13 Might be? Maybe you should check and be sure. Anyway, what is it you're really trying to do with the data?

Comment: You can't do nested loops over a string. `x` is iterating over the characters, so there's nothing left to iterate over.

Comment: If it's really JSON, you should be able to use `json.loads()` to parse it.

Comment: I am grabbing data from wayback machine; first I collect links by using API and this is what api returns

Comment: You can directly copy paste the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're really after are the count/statuscode/timestamp values, you don't need to parse the <strike>json</strike> list literally. <strike>Python will pull the json in as list/dict as needed.</strike> So to get past any "None" values, use the "if z:" conditional statement.

Once you get to where z exists, z.get('cnt','') will pull the field if it's there, or return nothing if it doesn't exist. You can then get into the status/date list using pop. The way I wrote that part isn't quite as elegant, but it'll get the job done. (This assumes the status/timestamp lists are always length 1. If that's not the case, you could insert some other logic/indexing in there pretty easily to pull the value you're interested in.)

```
for x in data:
    for y in x:
        for z in y:
            if z:
                count = z.get('cnt', '')
                st = z.get('st', '')
                if st:
                    status = st.pop()
                ts = z.get('ts', '')
                if ts:
                    date = ts.pop()

print(count, status, date)

2 200 20140308061038
```

UPDATED: Data is of type list.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_acceptable_string = data.replace("'", "\"").replace('None', 'null')
d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
```

Comment: Here is the example data, it is not json?

Comment: you are changing constantly your code, you have originally a str. As you have it right now, should work.